# Force Zend SOAP client to send `null` properties

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I'm sending a SOAP request with some nested data, and elements in the array which are `null` are being excluded from the request.

By simply recursively walking the array and `string`-casting all the elements, the client then includes them all; however I was wondering if there was a config option to do this behind the scenes in either the PHP `SoapClient` or Zend's own.

Comment: array_walk_recursive(
    $details,
    function (&$value) {
        $value = (string) $value;
    }
);

Comment: Maybe adding nillable=true in the xsd helps as written here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213538/null-values-in-php-soapclient-calls?

Comment: The problem is that I have no control over the WSDL - it's coming from an external service provider.